# Munin isn't showing graph history

Tags: cgi, munin, graph

I'm setting up my new Ubuntu 10.04 server and installed munin to view my machine's stats. It was working for a while, then I changed a couple of things (PHP spawn-fcgi to PHP FPM, reinstalled nginx) and now the graph history doesn't work.

I can see the current state, but no history on the graph:

[What my munin graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruRix.png) (sorry I can't post inline images due to reputation restrictions)

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the cron-based or the (new 2.0) cgi graphs generation?

Comment: I'm using the 2.0 cgi graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try aptitude purge munin-node && aptitude install munin-node to see if it helps. Before doing this backup munin configuration and munin rrd data files.

Comment: Yep, that worked! I guess I just needed to reinstall.